# in angularjs when modal closes goes back to home page

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog

I have a modal display when the user clicks an icon on the main menu. It is in the header template html.  This is the code:

```
<li class="navButton" style="float:right">
  <a href="#/reportSettingModal" id="reportSetting" ng-click="updateReportSetting()" title="ReportSetting">
        <i class="fa fa-cog" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </a>
 </li>
```

The close function is in the controller:

```
angular.module('vApp.controllers')
.controller('ReportSettingModalCtrl', [
    '$scope',
    '$rootScope',
    '$uibModal',
    'Session',
    '$uibModalInstance',
    function($scope, $rootScope, $uibModal, session,  $uibModalInstance){
            $scope.username = session.user;
          $scope.title = 'Report Settings';

    $scope.close = function() {
      $uibModalInstance.close();

    };
```

In each of the 3 pages that can display the modal I have this code:

```
$scope.updateReportSetting = function(){
                 $scope.selectModalInstance = $uibModal.open({
                templateUrl: 'views/reportSettingModal.html',
                controller: 'ReportSettingModalCtrl'
                 });
            }
```

The problem is that when the user clicks on the page Analyze and the modal is closed, the page shown is the home page not Analyze.
How can I keep the page that was originally displayed when the modal was clicked to still display when the modal is closed?

Comment: Why do you have an `href` on your anchor tag? Aren't you just using the anchor as button to fire that function? If so that could be your issue.

Comment: That did it!  I removed the href and the page does not go back to the home page.  I don't understand why it went to the home page with the href tag.  Could you give me more explanation?  Also, create an answer so I can credit you with solving the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the `href` attribute on the anchor tag.

The browser by default will attempt to load whatever is in the `href` into the url. So when you click on that element it will fire the click event along with the location update event. What Angular has done is made the [anchor a directive](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/a.js) in order to prevent that default option when the `href` or similar is not present on it. That is why removing that will prevent the navigation event from happening, leaving you the same page.

Having said that, if you aren't navigating to a new page it's more semantic to use a button rather than an anchor for reasons like this.